# jstree contextmenu access node attributes

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, jstree

I want to define a contextmenu where the items depend on some attributes of the node. My tree is set with json data  like 
...

```
    {
      "data": {
        "title":"SVK 01",
        "attr":{
          "class":"offer","id":"off336","xx":"YY_336"
        }
    }
   },
```

...

and I set mu contextmenu with :

```
    contextmenu : {
             "items": function(node) {
                 if (node.attr('xx') == 'Foo' ) {
                     ....
```

I would like to access the attributes here, 
for instance 
    node.attr('xx')

but I always get undefined.

It works  perfect in my callback when  clicking a node, but i have no idea how to access it when setting the contextmenu. 
Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

```
                "contextmenu": {
                    "items": function ($node) {
                        return {
                            "Ativar": {
                                "label": "Ativar",
                                "action": function (obj) {
                                    $("#jstree_div").jstree("enable_node", $node);
                                    var node = $('#jstree_div').jstree(true).get_node($node);
                                    alert($("#" + node.id).attr("class"));
                                }
                            },
                            "Desativar": {
                                "label": "Desativar",
                                "action": function (obj) {
                                    $("#jstree_div").jstree("disable_node", $node);
                                    var node = $('#jstree_div').jstree(true).get_node($node);
                                    alert($("#" + node.id).attr("class"));
                                }

                            }
                        };
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Please, add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
contextmenu: {
    items: {
         rename: {
             label: "Rename"
             action: function (node) {
                 var inst = $.jstree.reference(data.reference), obj = inst.get_node(data.reference);

                 var xx = obj.data.xx;
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/vakata/jstree/issues/1126

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
contextmenu : {
  "items": function(node) {
    if (node.data.attr.xx === 'Foo' ) {
      ....
```